# Allowing duplicate value slider entries using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, I have a slider which allows the user to submit their score into the Azure database, to do this the user has to move the slider to any number from their previous score. I want to change this now to allow the user to be able to submit the same score as their previous one now.

This is my code for my slider:

```
 <local:ExtendedRangeSlider 
        RangeEnd="100" 
        Name="{Binding Usersymptomid}" 
        Value="{Binding Lastfeedbackscore}" 
        RangeStart="100" 
        ShowValueLabel="false" 
        ShowRange="false" 
        TrackSelectionThickness="3"
        HeightRequest="40" 
        StepFrequency="1" 
        Grid.Row="4" 
        TickFrequency="10"   
        Grid.Column="0" 
        TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        Margin="0,0,0,8"  
        ValueChanging="Handle_ValueChanging"/>
```

And my submit button:

```
 async void SubmitFeedback_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
            var response = await DisplayAlert("Confirm Symptom Intensity", "Are you sure you want to change symptom intensity to " + rangeSlider.Value.ToString() + "?", "Cancel", "OK");
            if (response == false)
            {
                await AddSymptomFeedback(rangeSlider.IDValue, rangeSlider.Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new newviewsymptom());
                return;
            }
     }
```

The code originally gave the user an error message asking them to change the value and didn't post to the database, I've tried commenting that part out but nothing happens unless I change the value of the slider.

Comment: Is the same score submitted and no response?

Comment: @LeoZhu if the score stays the same nothing is submitted or no message shown, once the slider has been moved and the value has changed it works then.